# Rails nested model with formtastic is skipping one field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic, nested-attributes

I have this structure models

```
class Tournament < ActiveRecord::Base
  AGES = ["5u", "6u", "7u", "8u"]
  has_many  :courts, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :courts, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:name].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true

class Court < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tournament, :autosave => true
  has_many  :ages, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ages, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:name].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true

class Age < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :court
```

Now my forms look like this

_form.html.erb

```
<%= semantic_form_for @tournament do |f| %>
<%= f.inputs do %>
  <%= f.input :name, :hint => "What is the name of the Tournament?" %>
<%= f.semantic_fields_for :courts do |builder| %>
       <%= render :partial => "court_fields", :locals => { :f => builder } %>
   <% end %>
```

_court_fields.html.erb

```
<div class="nested_fields">
<%= f.input :name, :input_html => {:class => "name"} %>
<%= f.semantic_fields_for :ages do |builder| %>
  <%= render :partial => "age_fields", :locals => { :f => builder } %>
<% end %>
```

_age_fields.html.erb

```
 Testing ...am I getting in here
<%= f.input :name, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => Tournament::AGES, :input_html => {:class => "age_limits"} %>
```

everything seems to work well except nothing shows up in the ages_fields partial...not the checkboxes and not even the dummy text `Testing ...am I getting in here` is not displaying....any ideas what could be causing the issue

Comment: In _court_fields.html.erb you are calling the partial `age_fields`, while the partial is named _ages_fields.html.erb (Note the s in ages). Try changing that.

Comment: that was a typo...the partial is named _age_fields.html.erb

Comment: good catch but the partial is named correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious reason I can think of: are you sure your `Court` has `ages` ?

[EDIT] That the `Court` has the relation was indeed clear to me. 
But your code will only show an `age` for a `court` if it already exists.

From your output in the comments: the court has no actual ages so no ages are shown.

If you do this in your controller:

```
def new
  @tournament = Tournament.new
  @tournament.courts.build
  @tournament.courts[0].ages.build  
end
```

This will make sure that you have at least one (empty) court and one (empty) age.

Otherwise you could also consider using a gem like [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) to dynamically add new elements if needed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: if you look at the models i have above it does have....here is my rails console output  c = Court.first => #<Court id: 4, name: "tournament[courts_attributes][1][name]", address: "tournament[courts_attributes][1][address]", city: "tournament

Comment: c.ages
  Age Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `ages`.* FROM `ages` WHERE `ages`.`court_id` = 4
 => []

Comment: That was what I ment: the court has no actual ages, so none are shown. I edited my answer accordingly.